Inject default Context into go-grpc server (e.g. logger injection)
The golang go-grpc grpc.NewServer(...) call appears to lack any means to inject a default context.Context that should be inherited by all server gRPC call handlers.
Is there a sensible and simple way to do this? I didn't find anything like a WithContext or WithContextOption grpc.Option, and there's no grpc.NewServerWithContext(...) or the like. Nor a SetContext(...).
So far it looks like it's necessary to implement stream and unary interceptors that merge the server's default context with whatever you wish to inject into the context, with something like this example for injecting a logr into the context.Context:
// inject the passed logger into the gRPC call context for all inbound unary calls
// Works around go-grpc's lack of a WithContext option to set a root context
func loggingUnaryServerInterceptor(logger logr.Logger) grpc.UnaryServerInterceptor {
    return func(
        ctx context.Context,
        req interface{},
        info *grpc.UnaryServerInfo,
        handler grpc.UnaryHandler,
    ) (interface{}, error) {
        newCtx := logging.IntoContext(ctx, logger)
        return handler(newCtx, req)
    }
}

type contextStream struct {
    grpc.ServerStream
    ctx context.Context
}

func (s *contextStream) Context() context.Context {
    return s.ctx
}

// inject the passed logger into the gRPC call context for all inbound streaming calls
// by wrapping the ServerStream and overriding the Context() method
// Works around go-grpc's lack of a WithContext option to set a root context
func loggingStreamServerInterceptor(logger logr.Logger) grpc.StreamServerInterceptor {
    return func(srv any, ss grpc.ServerStream, info *grpc.StreamServerInfo, handler grpc.StreamHandler) error {
        newCtx := logging.IntoContext(ss.Context(), logger)
        return handler(srv, &contextStream{ss, newCtx})
    }
}

func run_my_server(ctx context.Context) {
    logger, err := logr.FromContext(ctx)
    if err == nil {
       panic("no logger in context")
    }
    grpcServer := grpc.NewServer(
        grpc.ChainUnaryInterceptor(
            loggingUnaryServerInterceptor(logger),
        ),
        grpc.ChainStreamInterceptor(
            loggingStreamServerInterceptor(logger),
        ),
    )
    // ...
}

Can this be right?  I have to subclass the grpc.ServerStream and everything?
I expected to be able to do something like
func run_my_server(ctx context.Context) {
    grpcServer := grpc.NewServer(
       // this DOES NOT EXIST, this is WRONG
       grpc.WithContext(ctx),
    )
    // ...
}

Equally surprising was not finding a canned middleware in logr itself.

With github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware (v1), the sensible and simple way is to write your own interceptors.
There will be a default context.Context passed to all gRPC handlers. If you wish to set values into that context the "right" way, chain your interceptors on the server.
Some popular libraries like zap provide their own off-the-shelf interceptors. If logr doesn't, you implement it yourself by injecting whatever dependency you need into the grpc.(Unary|Stream)ServerInterceptor.

With github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/v2 you have some more bridge types. Specifically, you want to implement logging.Logger and then pass it to logging.UnaryServerInterceptor.
s := grpc.NewServer(
    grpc.ChainUnaryInterceptor(
        logging.UnaryServerInterceptor(/* your logging.Logger implementation */),
    ),
)

For logr specifically, there's an example here: https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/blob/main/interceptors/logging/examples/logr/example_test.go

Thanks. I did notice the logging adapter in go-grpc-middleware/v2 but it forces switching logging interfaces or another wrap/unwrap layer. I was very surprised there's no generic way to set a root context for the gRPC server, or a func()(context.Context) that returns one on demand.

The root context is already provided by the grpc implementation. All other contexts that you can set with an interceptor can only be children. The logr example is pretty straightforward.

Agree it's not hard, but it's astonishingly verbose for what seems like such a simple and commonplace thing. I'm just very surprised there's no way to supply a root context to the gRPC server instead of having it use a hardcoded context.Background()
